# "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#

```cs
   void firstEntered(string input) {
        Terminal.WriteLine("Jen: Hello, James!");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Terminal.WriteLine("Jen: SSH Detected: You must be sick, ");
        Terminal.WriteLine("like last time.");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Terminal.WriteLine("Jen: Well don't worry. I'm sure you're ");
        Terminal.WriteLine("looking for your Bank Logs to find someones");
        Terminal.WriteLine("account number!");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Terminal.WriteLine("Jen: Well don't worry. I'll take you there now.");
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Terminal.WriteLine("cd Bank/");
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Terminal.WriteLine("cd User512/");
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Terminal.WriteLine("cd Log/");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Terminal.WriteLine("Jen: To see your logs, type ls.");
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        Terminal.WriteLine("Jen: I'll go now, bye!");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Terminal.WriteLine("REMINDER: Once you've found the password,");
        Terminal.WriteLine("run: Email -i [Pass] Garris@Exuno.com");

        if (input == "ls") {
        Terminal.WriteLine("Listing Bank Logs:30m");
        Terminal.WriteLine("New_Transaction to 921831");
        Terminal.WriteLine("Password_Update to Sonnie");
        Terminal.WriteLine("New_Transaction to 921831");
        Terminal.WriteLine("");
        Terminal.WriteLine("REMINDER: Once you've found the password,");
        Terminal.WriteLine("run: Email -i [Pass] Garris@Exuno.com");
            almostDone();
        }
        else {
            Terminal.WriteLine ("Unrecognized Command. Try again:");
        }
    }
```

Hello, I'm currently working on a game on Unity and while running the code I get this issue:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'input' of 'Gamescript.almostDone(string)'
>   I was wondering how I could fix this.
>   Thanks.

Comment: You're `almostDone` method obviously expects a string parameter, but you don't pass one. Either change the signature of `almostDone` if it doesn't require a string parameter, or pass one when you call it.

Comment: Or as a third option, keep the parameter but give it a default value.

Answer (score 1):

The `almostDone();` is accepting a `string` type argument, which is not provided. Pass some valid `string` parameter to the function to fix this issue. In case you do not require `string` parameter for this method, consider removing the parameter from the `almostDone();` method signature.

Comment: How could I do this?

Comment: Show us the `almostDone()` method pls.

Comment: ```
    void almostDone(string input) {
  Terminal.WriteLine("Listing Bank Logs:30m");
  Terminal.WriteLine("New_Transaction to 921831");
  Terminal.WriteLine("Password_Update to Sonnie");
  Terminal.WriteLine("New_Transaction to 921831");
  Terminal.WriteLine("");
     Terminal.WriteLine("REMINDER: Once you've found the password,");
     Terminal.WriteLine("run: Email -i [Pass] Garris@Exuno.com");

  if (input == "Email -i [Pass] Garris@Exuno.com") {
   firstDone();
  }

  else {
   Terminal.WriteLine("Command Not Authorized or found.");
  }
```

Comment: So the method signature is `almostDone(string input)`. The value `input` is used in the method to check if it an Email. So you need to pass some valid `string` variable while calling this method.

Comment: Ah, so I need to change (string input) to something else?

Comment: If you want the `input` parameter to be optional, you can pass some default value to it and change it like `almostDone(string input == "someDefaultString")` Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments